# Value cannot be null. An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis-7

I am running my project in my localhost, i am pointing to http://localhost:64495/Service.svc?wsdl in my browser to see it, but i am getting an exception below

Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type

**Stack Trace**

[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type]
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +10898802
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +6
   Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationManager..cctor() +141

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationManager' threw an exception.]
   Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationManager.get_IisBinPath() +17
   Microsoft.Web.Administration.WebConfigurationManager..cctor() +68

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Web.Administration.WebConfigurationManager' threw an exception.]
   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +489276
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +178
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpModule.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult ar) +350382
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +9692161
```

Comment: check your `Microsoft.web.Administation.ConfigurationManager` Version ,

Comment: Hi Webruster, My Microsoft.Web.Administration version is 7.0.0.0.